# Require all GitHub enterprise code owners to approve before merge

Tags: github

Is there any way to require **all** of the listed code owners (for the same changed file) in the CODEOWNERS file to approve before a pull request can be merged?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer from lee-dohm on https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/CODEOWNER-Required-Reviews/m-p/15422#M4786:

"No, there currently isn't a way to do that built-in to the CODEOWNERS feature. If that was the one and only rule, you could do a hacky solution where you required a PR to have three approvals to be merged but if the CODEOWNERS contents ever changed, you would have to remember to manually update the number of required reviews. So it isn't something I would recommend as a solution to the question you're asking."